# Trouble with onPush change detection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-changedetection

I am trying to implement onPush change detection in one of my components

**component.html**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let data of data" [innerHTML]="getName(data)"></li>
</ul>
```

**component.ts**

```
getData() {
  this._store.select('data')
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.DATA = result;
      this.sortData();
    });
}

getFilters() {
  this._store.select('filters')
    .subscribe(result => {
      this.filters = result;
      this.sortData();
    });
}

sortData() {
  this.data = Array.from(new Set(this.DATA.filter(x => ... filters));
}

getName(data) {
  return `Super Cool ${data.name}`;
}
```

but I can't seem to figure it out.

Basically I have data that is coming in and a user can filter this data, now each time the data is filtered or new data is recieved it should trigger the onPush change detection and update the list on the html page.. but It isnt working..

Now I am aware of the async pipe but I'm not sure how I would implement it in this case

Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

I understand that to trigger the change detection you need to update the object reference but isnt that what

```
this.data = Array.from(new Set(this.DATA.filter(x => ... filters));`
```

is doing??

Answer (score 1):

Object changes do not trigger on push change detection, that is only true for component inputs. What you want to do here is use the async pipe

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.data$ = this._store.select('data').pipe(
     map(d => Array.from(new Set(d)))
   )
 }
```

Then in template somewhere around where you need DATA:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf=“data$ | async as DATA”>
```

The async pipe always triggers on push

Comment: I have edited my question to be more specific.. I'm not sure how your answer would work in my situation

Comment: As I stated, changing an object reference does NOT trigger change detection except on an input reference. You just need to do whatever data manipulation in the map function.

Comment: Yeah sure the data manipulation the first time will work in the map function, but how do I trigger the change detection when a new filter has been applied? as shown in my example?

Comment: You set up a second observable of the filters and combine them

Comment: How exactly would I do that?