# State change not detected when using OnPush Change Detection?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Trying to figure out why `OnPush` change detection strategy is not working [In this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zfkjy3?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fdetect.component.ts).

If I understand correctly `OnPush` change detection should be triggered when a property reference changes. and in order to ensure this a new array is set each time like this:

```
    this.periodData$.subscribe((pd) => {
      this.periodData = [...pd];
    });
```

And the template that renders `periodData` looks like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let p of periodData">{{p}}</div>
```

The `periodData` is changed via the select control in the demo.

We can see that it is changing via the log, however the template is not updating.  If change detection is set to default then it works.

Thoughts?

Comment: It seems you're creating a new array every time you update ```periodData```. But angular change detection may not be recognizing this as a change, because the reference to the ```periodData``` itself has not changed. Have you try use ```ChangeDetectorRef``` to manually trigger change detection? ```import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';```

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation thanks I may give `ChangeDetectorRef` that a shot.

Comment: Yes that's a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ChangeDetectorRef` to manually trigger change detection after updating `periodData`.

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  ViewEncapsulation,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import { AsyncPipe, NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-detect',
  imports: [NgFor, AsyncPipe],
  standalone: true,
  template: `
 <div *ngFor="let p of periodData">{{p}}</div>
  `,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class DetectComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  periodData$!: Observable<any[]>;
  periodData: any[] = [];

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.periodData$.subscribe((pd) => {
      console.log(`Period Data is ${JSON.stringify(pd)}`);
      this.periodData = [...pd];
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool!!  I updated the a demo to go with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1ugthr?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fdetect.component.ts

Comment: You show use the AsyncPipe instead. You have a memory leak here.

Comment: I deleted the AsyncPipe from the imports.  It still has a memory leak though because the subscription is not terminated using something like [ngneat/until-destroy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngneat/until-destroy), but should be fine for demo purposes.

Answer (score 0):

[Ah - OK - I found the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59655048/trouble-with-onpush-change-detection).  In short:

> Object changes do not trigger on push change detection, that is only true for component inputs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35401360)

Comment: @user67275 How is that link-only?  They quoted the relevant portion.